# Applying Nested If condition to dataframe -Python

Tags: python, sql-server, dataframe, if-statement

I am connecting to SQL database and generating data frame with a sleep time of 5 mins for 2 hours between 4 to 6 AM and trying to check job status, below are conditions which I'm trying to implement.

Looping over ll the jobs, what I want to do is:

If any job is RUNNING and check it if is taking within the estimated time.

- If yes then print (" is running fine within estimated time")
  else print(" has passed out of estimated time").
- Else check if the last job is completed then print("all jobs completed").

Below is the data:

[image]

My code:

```
i=0
while i <12:
    
    todays_run="select * from table where getdate()=startdate"  /*Checking for rundate as todays date*/
    result=pd.read_sql(todays_run,sql_conn)
    if result.empty:
        print(' No jobs are running  :')
    elif result[result.status=='RUNNING' and result.start_date <result.estimated_end]:
        print("Below  jobs are currently running with estimated time \n\n ",result)
    else print("Jobs taking long time",<job_name>)
    elsif result[result.status=='COMPLETED' and result.jobname='A']
        print("all jobs are completed \n \n ")
    time.sleep(60)
exit(1)
```

I'm getting an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Is this possible to implement using python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Series mask can help in this situation.  Each of your logical conditions, applied to each row of a DataFrame, makes a list/Series of True/False values.

You can then access rows with `df.loc[mask]`, and convert logical "and" to bitwise mask "&" to combine masks together.  I also like to say `mask.any()` or `mask.all()` depending on the logical test.  These tricks help me do the steps you're trying to achieve.

Here's some of the ideas you're trying to achieve, converted to a Series mask.

```py
for i in range(12):
    # Checking for rundate as todays date
    todays_run="select * from table where getdate()=startdate"
    result=pd.read_sql(todays_run,sql_conn)
    running_mask = result["status"] == 'RUNNING'
    completed_mask = result["status"] == 'COMPLETED'
    jobname_a_mask = result["jobname"] == 'A'
    estimated_mask = result["start_date"] < result["estimated_end"]
    if result.empty:
        print(' No jobs are running  :')
    elif (running_mask & estimated_mask).any():
        print("Below  jobs are currently running with estimated time \n\n ",
            result.loc[running_mask & estimated_mask])
    else (jobname_a_mask & completed_mask).all():
        print("all jobs are completed \n \n ")
    time.sleep(60)
exit(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `elif` conditions you are possibly evaluating multiple rows at once. This is why you receive that error.
If you don't care how many rows respect your condition, you could try:

```py
elif (result[result.status=='RUNNING' and result.start_date <result.estimated_end]).any()
```

Or, if you need all the rows to respect your condition, replace `.any()` with `.all()`